# get string from edittext android being error

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm beginner android. i have problem about to get text string from edit view. please help me fix it. thanks so much.
CommentActivity.java

```
public class CommentActivity extends Fragment  {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    TextView cmt;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_layout, container, false);
        Button send = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.send_comment);
        cmt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_comment);
        ListView lst = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_comments);
        String[] values = new String[] {};
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
               public void onClick(View v)
               {
                   CharSequence content = cmt.getText();
                   cmt.setText("");
                   adapter.add((String) content);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            });
        return v;
    }
}
```

its error:

```
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813): Uncaught exception
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
cannot be cast to java.lang.String
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at RanhTV.Controller.CommentActivity$1.onClick(CommentActivity.java:36)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-11 16:39:10.244: E/PlayerDetailActivity(25813):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: instead of casting use toString method to add string in Array list as : `adapter.add(content.toString());`

Answer (score 5):

just put

```
adapter.add(String.valueOf(cmt.getText());
```

Comment: thanks it work. but i have new error, if you can help me, please.
Process: RanhTV.Controller, PID: 29327
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExceptionat java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:179)
atRanhTV.Controller.CommentActivity$1.onClick(CommentActivity.java:36)

Answer (score 0):

```
String content = cmt.getText().toString();
cmt.setText("");
adapter.add(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below:

```
adapter.add(content.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(content.length());
sb.append(content);
adapter.add(sb.toString());`

Answer (score -1):

It should be this way,

```
  String content = cmt.getText().toString();
   adapter.add(content);
```